# How can I disable/restrict executable premission for my download directory?

Tags: permissions

During my daily work I like to use the "Type to search" function to start programs quickly and easily however I am always afraid of running something uncontrolled/unchecked thing from my download directory. Is there a way to avoid this problem without paying more attention and using something technical?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Is this about the Gnome Launcher to limit the searching directory? Or hide Downloads folder from you?